# Scrapy: X Path choose all headers where ancestor is not footer

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get all headers which are not in the footer.

So the header `<h3 class="ibm-bold">Discover</h3>` should be excluded from the scrape.

```
<footer role="contentinfo" aria-label="IBM">
   <div class="region region-footer">
   <div id="ibm-footer-module">
    <section role="region" aria-label="Resources">
            <h3 class="ibm-bold">Discover</h3>
```

I have tried using this expression to select the headers which should be excluded, but it doesn't return the right nodes.

```
//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4 or self::h5 or self::h6]/ancestor::footer/text()
```

The page I am scraping is this: https://www.ibm.com/products/informix/embedded-for-iot?mhq=iot&mhsrc=ibmsearch_a

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it.

```
//*[
  (self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4 or self::h5 or self::h6)
  and not(ancestor::footer)
]/text()
```